# Django and strftime best practices

Tags: django, django-localflavor

Could someone please comment on best practices regarding formatting dates in Django?

More specifically I am trying to get the current day (Monday, Tuesday,...) translated in the current active language in Django.

Using x.strftime('%A') always yields the day in English, which may not be the current language in Django.

Thanks x.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

`from django.utils.formats import date_format`